# Android TableLayout wrap content

Tags: android, text, cell, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I have a `LinearLayout` with `TableLayout` and `LinearLayout` inside. `TableLayout` is made up of 5 `TableRow`s. Each `TableRow` is made up of two `View` objects.

Firt column has two `TextView`s, my problem is that the text of `TexView` is wrapped:

The word `SomeValue` is wrapped, the letter `e` is a in new line, I'd like all in just one row, in this case and in general case, wath's the way pattern?

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_small" 
    android:id="@+id/layout1">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:stretchColumns="0,true"
        android:shrinkColumns="*,true">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Value1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerPrefix"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
        **<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SomeValue"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/valueU"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>**
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Mytext"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
               />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/valueN"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AnyValue"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center">
  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioM"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="M" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioF"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="F" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRegistrazione"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send Data" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

For each textview you could add

```
android:singleLine = "true"
```

That will make it a single line. If the text is too big then you could use [ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize)

```
android:ellipsize
```

to control how you want the text to appear

Comment: Hi Zoltan, I just tried your code but: 1) if I use android:singleLine = "true"  appear: "SomeVal..." 2) if I use "ellipsize" directive, I get a troncate word. I'd like know if possible to have each word,just in one row,without truncatre or ... PS:are right directive "android:stretchColumns="0,true" android:shrinkColumns="*,true" ?! thank you!!